# Where have all my Maps reviews gone?

Tags: google-plus, google-maps

Over the years, I have posted a few reviews of places I've visited on Google Maps. Occasionally, I like to look back at my reviews, to remind myself where I've been. I'm aware that these reviews are now a part of Google+, but when I look at my [list of reviews](https://plus.google.com/115077192943664521829/reviews), only 3 of them appear. Google+ indicates that I have a total of 15 reviews, but clicking the "More" link at the bottom of the page does nothing.

Is that page's function just broken at the moment? Have my reviews been lost to time as a part of the new Google Maps roll out (or for some other arcane reason)? Is there another way to view or search for all the reviews I've posted?

Comment: Do the places you commented still exist?

Comment: Yes. And even if some don't, it's highly unlikely that I rated 12 places that all happened to disappear in the span of a year or two.

Comment: I've found the reviews feature of Google Maps to be wholly unreliable (try to write a review of my local railway station and you get a blank page). Perhaps this is Google's way of quietly deprecating it. It's a shame.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I know this is an old statement, but I highly doubt they are phasing out reviews as they just revamped the Google Guides program scoring.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the answer is still actual so I'm posting this for the benefit of future readers.

It appears that Google Reviews can be deleted for many reasons ([source](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Enhance-Your-Presence/Why-are-genuine-reviews-deleted/td-p/492045#)):

1. <strike>Your G+ account is empty or shows little activity before/after the review</strike> (not relevant anymore, G+ kicked the bucket on 2019)
2. You left a negative review and the business owner asked for its deletion
3. Your review contains URLs
4. The same review appears elsewhere online
5. You are the business' owner, an employee, or an ex-employee ([article](https://gizmodo.com/google-maps-no-longer-lets-you-post-negative-reviews-ab-1821649985))
6. The review was posted from the same IP address of the business
7. The review was posted from the same IP address of other reviews for the same business
8. The review was posted from the IP address of a SEO company
9. The review was posted from a totem (tablet, computer etc.) for customers at the business' place
10. You tried repeatedly to review the same place
11. The business has an abnormal number of reviews, or a high number of reviews in a short time frame
12. No reason, or pretty much whatever Google feels like at the moment

A number of my legitimate reviews have been deleted, too, and without letting me know the reason. It's very annoying.

Note the point #2: A business owner can unilaterally decide to delete a bad review, and even a bad star rating with no review. I've seen businesses systematically removing all reviews with less than four stars. When you give a star rating which gets deleted, the stars rating still appears when you look at the place from your Google account but it's not shown publicly anymore nor taken into account for the average rating. (See also [this article](https://whitespark.ca/blog/google-remove-reviews/).)

**Hence I'd recommend not to bother writing negative (or even positive, for that matter) Google reviews anymore, because they will likely disappear.** You can still assign star ratings as a personal reminder of how crappy or awesome the place was, just for you.

As a consequence, and also because of my personal experience of going into places which had 4/5 stars on Google Maps and turned out to be awful, it can be said without doubt that **Google Maps ratings are unreliable and misleading, so you should not consider them as a guide neither you should waste your time writing reviews on Google**. Rather, use sites that actually provide a service to customers and value their reviews - such as TrustPilot and Yelp (businesses), TripAdvisor (hotels, bars, restaurants), GlassDoor (companies). All these sites don't allow reviewed places to remove unfavorable reviews, so they are reliable.

Personal anecdote: I live near the border of an European country, and for the last 10+ years have been crossing the border to run errands and visit friends at least twice a week. About six months ago, it seems that Google decided that a large area I used to visit periodically in the adjacent country was the Forbidden Zone, because now every time I review a business there I get a mail saying "Google moderation systems and processes identified content that may be fake engagement", and my review is refused.